# How to batch read data in pouchdb?

Tags: pouchdb, nosql

I have a list of itemIds say `[1,2,3,4]`, What I want to do here is to get all the data from db with these itemIds. Is there any easy way to do that?

All I can think of now is as follow:

```
[1,2,3,4].forEach((v,i)=>{
      db.find({
        selector: {itemId: v}    
      }).then((result) => {
        sCb && sCb(result.docs)
      }).catch((err) => {
        fCb && fCb(err)
        console.log(err) 
      });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.find({
    selector: "$or": [
        {itemId: 1},
        {itemId: 2},
        {itemId: 3},
        {itemId: 4}
    ]
  })
```

or:

```
db.find({
    selector: {itemId: { "$in": [1,2,3,4] }}
  })
```